# How to pass value from page 1 to page 3?

Tags: android

I have 3 pages in my app, and it have to go to page 1 -> 2 -> 3 as sequence

and I want to send value from page 1 to page 3 how to send it without through page 2

How to code it?

////edit

I use

```
Intent toPage3 = new Intent(getParent(), page3.class);
Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
dataBundle.putString("value",value);
toPage3.putExtras(dataBundle);

Intent toPage2 = new Intent(getParent(), page2.class);
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
parentActivity.startChildActivity("CategoriesTabActivity", toPage2);
```

but page 3 can't recieve the value

What should I do?

Comment: By pages you mean activities?

Comment: Could you explain what type of data it is an what you're trying to archive? I think then we can tell you the best way how to pass you data.

Comment: How you have received toPage3 on 3rd activity. Can you post the code

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Intents, they can act as a message transport between activities.

[Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

[Intent and Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

Answer (score 0):

use intent.putextra(). you will not need to go via second page. Learn from developer.android.com about this.

use this on sending activity

```
     Intent bin= new Intent(this,B.class);
        bin.putExtra("a","b");
        bin.putExtra("c",12);
```

and this on receiving

```
    Intent call=getIntent();
               String s=call.getStringExtra("a");
               int d=call.getIntExtra("c", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Activities are based on Intents so you move from Activity X to Activity Y by sending an intent from x to y. that have some extras.

So you can just do this by calling

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, myActiviyY.class);
myIntent.putExtra(String,String);
```

Read more about [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)

Answer (score 0):

the page3 didn't receive the value because you past it from the page2 , but in your code, you pass to the page3 from the page2 , so you should pass the value from page1 to page 2 , and then you can pass it the page 3 , i dont think that is possible to pass it wthout page2 ,

the second thing :

you dont have `:parentActivity.startChildActivity("CategoriesTabActivity", toPage3);`  launched from your page1 , so your intent toPage3 is unuseful , you should  pass through page2 ,